# swing substance look&feel download

Tags: java, swing, substance, lf

Where do I download Substance L&F for Swing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The incredibly sloppy java.net transition has discarded the old download links, they're gone gone gone.  Kirill's solution is simply to post the code to GitHub.  See his [blog post about it](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/12/21/status-update-on-java-net-projects.html).

As a consequence, I have forked the distro to do maintenance and upkeep.  Read [my blog post about it](http://shemnon.com/speling/2011/04/insubstantial-62-release.html).

Comment: @Harry Joy @milan BTW do you guys know when they plan to sort it out all this transition of java.net I didn't hear any update about it?

Comment: That time has come and past, obviously things didn't transition that well.  What's broken will remain broken unless individual project owners come in and clean things up, which Kirill has expressed that he won't.

Answer (score 3):

May be at [substance.dev.java.net](https://substance.dev.java.net/) Also [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.java.net.substance/substance/6.0/org/pushingpixels/substance/api/skin/SubstanceOfficeBlue2007LookAndFeel.java) you will find source code for all and can also download them all.

Also see [here](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect/org/java/net/substance/substance/6.0/substance-6.0.jar).

Answer (score 3):

You can Insubstantial (an excellent fork of the Substance L&F) at http://insubstantial.posterous.com/